# Element type is invalid when using react-native-off-canvas-menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have this menu using [react-native-off-canvas-menu](https://github.com/shoumma/react-native-off-canvas-menu):

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Icon } from 'react-native'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { togglePageMenu } from './menu.action'
import { OffCanvas3D } from 'react-native-off-canvas-menu'
import SearchPage from '../search-page/SearchPage'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isOpen: state.get('menu').get('isOpen')
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  togglePageMenu: () => {
    dispatch(togglePageMenu())
  }
})

let Menu = (props) => (
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <OffCanvas3D
      active={props.isOpen}
      onMenuPress={props.togglePageMenu}
      backgroundColor={'#222222'}
      menuTextStyles={{ color: 'white' }}
      handleBackPress={true}
      menuItems={[
        {
          title: 'Menu 1',
          icon: <Icon name="camera" size={35} color='#ffffff' />,
          renderScene: <SearchPage />
        }
      ]} />
  </View>
)
Menu.propTypes = {
  togglePageMenu: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isOpen: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired
}

Menu = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Menu)

export default Menu
```

When I add it to my app in another component's `render` method:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Container >
        <SearchPage />
        <Menu />
      </Container>
    )
  }
```

I get the error:

> ExceptionsManager.js:71 Unhandled JS Exception: Element type is
>   invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a
>   class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
>
> Check the render method of `Menu`.

I can't figure out why I get that error. Any ideas?

EDIT: When I delete the `renderScene` property in the menu it doesn't have the error. I am importing searchPage correctly. To prove the point I delete SearchPage and use a `<View></View>` in `renderScene` and get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is render menu component inside the container without passing any props, but the props are needed by the menu component such as, isOpen and togglePageMenu.

You need to do this in order to get rid of error:-

```
<Menu togglePageMenu= { () => this.yourFunctionName() } isOpen={true/false} />
```

Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks, but not the issue as I'm using redux which is why I don't specify the props like that.

Comment: oopss! i didn't saw that :)

Answer (score 0):

It was actually the `Icon` property in the `menuItems` property that caused the issue, of all things. It didn't give a very good error message because I had imported the wrong type of Icon. It was expecting `import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons'`. Possibly could help someone else using the react-native-off-canvas-menu so will leave it up.